# Cuda 4 inter-GPU synchronization

Tags: cuda, multi-gpu

Did anyone successfully test this feature on Cuda4 ? It seems I can't have it worked correctly, not sure if it's a bug in my code or the feature is not fully implemented yet.

For example, I want to do a kernel call after copying a memory from 1 gpu to another. Stream 0, mem0 is created on gpu0 stream 1,mem1 is created on gpu1. Both are Fermi Tesla (C2070)

```
cudaMemcpyAsync( mem1, mem0, size, cudaMemcpyDefault, stream0 );
cudaEventRecord(P2Pevent, stream0);

cudaStreamWaitEvent(stream1, P2Pevent, 0);
cudaKernel<<<block,thread,0,stream1>>>(mem1);
```

Sometime it seems the memory is not ready for the kernel yet so the result is incorrect. If I add an cudaDeviceSynchronize on Gpu0 then it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use cudaMemcpyPeerAsync to do direct inter-gpu memory copies. And both GPUs have to support peer to peer access, which is presently only supported on Fermi Telsa cards.

Comment: @talonmies I enable PeerAccess before that so I can use cudaMemcpyAsync directly. So the copying is precisely working, just that I can't synchronize on the other GPU. (as I said both of them are Fermi card )

Comment: You are stream-waiting for P2Pevent on stream1 but you have recorded it on stream0. Is that a typo?

Comment: do you have a TESLA card or only 480 Fermi cards? this operation works only on $$$ TESLA cards.

Comment: @fabrizio: Fermi Tesla brother, I confirm again that the P2P is working

Comment: @LumpN: So I record stream0 to P2PEvent, and stream 1 is waiting for it to be finished. Does that make sense ?

Comment: @iKid, Fermi != Fermi Tesla, B R O. Are you checking return errors from each API Call ?

Comment: @fabrizioM sorry, I really don't want to make a fuss here, but what I mean from the beginning is the P2P itself worked correctly because if I remove all the kernel call later the result is there in the 2nd gpu. The only problem is I can't synchronize it with other even. I did check and there is no error. If you got it working, let me know I will have to check my program.

Comment: @iKid, Does it work if you put NULL as a stream ? I can't reproduce because I don't have two Fermi Tesla Cards :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in my code ! It does work correctly
Thanks guys